# My Google Maps JavaScript is not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I am trying to create a Google map with a polygon overlay to load on my website. When I load the page the text shows but the map does not load.

I am new to javascript and am not entirely sure what I'm doing and a fresh (experienced) pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

The code below is located in an html page. The div specs are all defined in a css file and the coordinates for the overlay are in a linked javascript file.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greatredoubtData.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.003207, -73.610312),
      zoom: 16,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps1k'),mapOptions);
var greatredoubt = createOverlay();
  greatredoubt.setMap(map);

  }

  function createOverlay() {
    var overlayCoords = new Array ();

    var processedData = greatredoubtData.split(";");

    for (var i=0; i<processedData.length; i++) {
    var myCoords = processedDate[i].split(",");
    overlayCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(xyCoords[0], xycoords[1]));

  }

    var myOverlay = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: overlayCoords,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35

  });

    return myOverlay
  }


  </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="initialize">

  <p class="subtitle">Great Redoubt Prescribed Burn</p>
  <p>Saratoga National Historical Park</p>

  <div id="maps1" name="maps1">
  </div>

  <p class="caption">Date:  April 22, 2011
  </br>
Location:  LAT: 43.0023593/LON: -73.6106062/ LAT:43.0061421/LON:-73.6139449 (Tour Road Stop 9 & 10,       Saratoga NHP, Stillwater, NY)
  </br>
Burn Boss:  Jeff Wells, National Park Service
  </br>
Acres: 20/15 (planned)
  </br>
Primary Goals: reduce hazard fuels around historic structures, and maintain the cultural landscape of   open fields and vistas for the visiting public, thereby eliminating mechanical mowing.
  </p>

  </body>
```

Comment: where is maps1k i thinks it should be maps1 in your javascript code here var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps1k'),mapOptions);

Comment: And also do not forget to give  height and width for the maps1 div

Comment: You are missing the parentheses in the call of initialize

Answer (score 0):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/qtpx8/) its working now

```
 <div id="maps1" name="maps1" style="width:400px;height:600px;">
 </div>
```